# What is the difference between kill-ring-save and copy-region-as-kill?

Tags: yank, kill-ring

These two commands seem identical to me. What am I missing?

Comment: Did you ask `C-h f`?

Answer (score 5):

Documentation for `kill-ring-save`:

> [...] This command is similar to ‘copy-region-as-kill’, except that it gives
>   visual feedback indicating the extent of the region being copied.

Documentation for `copy-region-as-kill`:

> [...] This command’s old key binding has been given to ‘kill-ring-save’.

You can use `C-h f <function-name>` to show the help of the function.